# How to invoke kernel with serial console?

Tags: 12.04, server, software-installation, serial-port

How do I invoke the kernel with serial console on 12.04?

In 10.04 I could just add `console=ttyS0` in kernel line or `install quiet console=ttyS0` on boot: line

How do I do that in 12.04?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing special in 12.04. Just follow the information from: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SerialConsoleHowto

1) Paste the following into /etc/init/ttyS0.conf

```
# ttyS0 - getty
#
# This service maintains a getty on ttyS0 from the point the system is
# started until it is shut down again.

start on stopped rc or RUNLEVEL=[2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec /sbin/getty -L 9600 ttyS0 vt102
```

2) Ask upstart to start the getty

```
sudo start ttyS0
```

This will get you access to console. To get access to Linux init console, configure grub.

1) Edit /etc/default/grub to contain the following lines

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty1 console=ttyS0,9600n8"
GRUB_TERMINAL=serial
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=9600 --unit=0 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"
```

2) update grub

```
sudo update-grub
```

---

I am using 9600 just because I am using a server where the BIOS is already redirected over seria using 9600. If you don't care about the BIOS settings, feel free to use a faster serial line.

Enjoy!